# Ruby on Rails - Problems with controller method show in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now i am finishing my small learning project but I am sturggling with one thing. The funcionalities of the project are: `register`, `login`, `logout` for the **Author**; `creating`, `editing`, `removing` of the **Events**; attend, un-attend event.

Last thing what I want to implement is, to be able to see who is attending certain event. The functionality of attending / un-attending is already done (made a table Eventattendences with references to **events** and **author**).

The only thing which is missing is showing WHO is attending different event (that means to show Authors_key from the eventattendances table where events_id is equal in my show.html.erb). When i am trying to do that i always get an empty object from the SHOW method of eventattendacnes_controller.

Adding here all the code that should be related to this (if anything is missing just let me know and I will add it here). THANK YOU!

```
Versions: Rails(4.0.0), Ruby(2.3.3p222)
```

**eventattendances_controller**

```
class EventattendancesController < ApplicationController
  before_action  only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :require_login



def new
  if Eventattendance.exists?(events_id: params[:event_id].to_i, authors_id: current_user.id)
    redirect_to event_path(params[:event_id])
  else
    @eventattendance = Eventattendance.new(events_id: params[:event_id].to_i, authors_id: current_user.id)
    @eventattendance.save
    redirect_to event_path(params[:event_id])
  end
end

def destroy
  if Eventattendance.exists?(events_id: params[:event_id].to_i, authors_id: current_user.id)
    Eventattendance.where(events_id: params[:event_id].to_i, authors_id: current_user.id).first.destroy
    redirect_to event_path(params[:event_id])
  else
    redirect_to event_path(params[:event_id])
  end
end

def show
  @eventattendances = Eventattendance.find(events_id= params[:event_id].to_i)
end


 private
 def author_params
   params.require(:author).permit(:username, :email, :password,:password_confirmation)
 end

 def event_params
   params.require(:event).permit(:title, :body)
 end
   end
```

**eventattendances.rb** (Model)

```
  class Eventattendance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :event
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Events::Application.routes.draw do

 root to: 'events#index'
 resources :events
 resources :authors
 resources :author_sessions, only: [ :new, :create, :destroy ]
 resources :eventattendances, only: [:destroy, :new, :show]
 get 'login'  => 'author_sessions#new'
 get 'logout' => 'author_sessions#destroy'
end
```

**views/events/show.html.erb** (here i want to set the show function from eventattendances to show the authors_id of the authors that are attending the event)

```
 `<h1><%= @event.title %></h1>
  <p><%= @event.body %></p>     
  <%= @at_list.blank? %>
  <%= @at_list_att.blank? %>
  <%=sql = "Select * from eventattendances"
   at_list = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) %>

   <% @event.eventattendances.map do |eventattendance| %>
     <tr>
     <td><%= eventattendance.author_id %></td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>

   <%= link_to "<< Back to Event List", events_path %>

   <p> </p>
   <br>

   <% if logged_in? %>
   <%= link_to "edit", edit_event_path(@event) %>
   <%= link_to "delete", event_path(@event), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
   <% end %>


<%= link_to "Cancel atendance", eventattendance_path(event_id: @event.id), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<%= link_to "Attend", new_eventattendance_path(event_id: @event.id), class: "btn btn-success"%>
```

`

**events_controller**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
include EventsHelper
before_filter :require_login, except: [:index]

def index
  @events = Event.all
end

def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @event = Event.new

end



def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @event.save

  redirect_to event_path(@event)
end

def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy
  redirect_to events_path
end

def edit
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.update(event_params)

  redirect_to event_path(@event)
end



private
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :body)
end
end
```

**author.rb**

```
`class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   authenticates_with_sorcery!
   validates_confirmation_of :password, message: "should match confirmation", if: :password
   has_and_belongs_to_many :events


 end`
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put it into the **show** method of `events_controller.rb` (instead of `eventattendances_controller`)

`@eventattendances = Eventattendance.find_by(events_id: params[:id])`

+

to change the arguments of the find:

from `(events_id= params[:event_id])` to `(events_id: params[:id])`

(maybe it is going to help someone in the future)

Answer (score 1):

In first place, if you are rendering the `views/events/show` you could do

```
    <% @event.eventattendances.map do |eventattendance| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= eventattendance.author_id %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

to get the author_id.

But thinking better, maybe you are having a problem of relations and you need a
[has and belongs to many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Comment: Ok i changed it inside of my model files (i added them into my post). I changed the method in `Show.htm.erb` but i am still getting this error `undefined method eventattendances' for #<Event:0x593bd10> ` .. A question, do i need to do some migrations when i changed the model file? Because with this i am not really sure. Or any other suggestions what to do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, because with the has_belongs_to_many, you should use `@event.authors.map do |author|
  <tr>
        <td><%= author.id %></td>
      </tr>
<end>
`
Because you not need to call the intermediate table, if I'm correct

Comment: OK i tried and this is the result: `Could not find table 'authors_events'`. It looks like it wont work. I am just thinking if i need only the authors that are inside the eventattendance with the events_id which is active right now (in show). Do you think i can acquire this state with this command?